# Vim solarized seems to mixup color

Tags: debian, vim, vimrc

My vim:

[image]

This is how my looks, look at the change in color from line 38 onwards. Any solution for this?

Comment: Use Plugin's issue tracker

Comment: Put `let g:solarized_termtrans = 1` in `~/.vimrc` or `:set t_Co=256`.